# Use type of values and make another object in the same structure but with string as values and also deep nesting

Tags: typescript

Say we have a TypeScript type like this:

```
type FormValues = {
 name: string
 organization: {
   name: string
   telephone: string
   employees: number
 }
}
```

Based on this type I want to have a TypeScript utility which results in the following type:

```
type ErrorValues = {
 name?: string
 organization?: {
   name?: string
   telephone?: string
   employees?: string
 }
}
```

So I can have something like this:

```
const errors: ErrorUtility<FormValues>

console.log({ employeesError: errors?.organization.employees })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) types:

```
type ErrorUtility<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends number | string | boolean ? string : ErrorUtility<T[K]>;
}
```

This says something like:

> For any key `K` in the input type `T`, there is a key `K` in the
> resulting type such that the value is optional and either:
>
> - a string, in the case of a primitive value type; or
> - itself an error object, recursively.

Here's a playground showing it in use: https://tsplay.dev/wXk3LW